# How to Reverse Proxy Raw TCP Packets

Tags: apache-2.2, routing

I am designing a system where remote devices securely send status updates to a central logging server for aggregation. On the server I am using the Redis + Logstash + Elasticsearch solution. The data being sent to the server is sensitive and must be encrypted. I am struggling to find an efficient and secure means to 'LPUSH' the logs to the Redis list.

The devices are currently capable of sending the following Redis command directly to port 6379.

`"*3\r\n$5\r\nLPUSH\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n"`

The correct key and list entry are created within Redis on the server.

The next step is to put redis behind a firewall and encrypt the packets. My current attempt was to use Apache as a reverse proxy. A device would make a 2-way SSL connection to Apache and then reverse proxy the decreypted information to port 6379 using the loopback interface. The 2-way SSL connection is made without problems and a message is forwarded to Redis. Unfortunately it is not the message the device sent. tcpdump tells me the following...

`tcpdump -nnXvv -i lo host localhost and port 6379`

```
127.0.0.1.48916 > 127.0.0.1.6379: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfeab (incorrect -> 0x9415),
seq 1:132, ack 1, win 1025, options [nop,nop,TS val 299310518 ecr 299310518], 
length 131
0x0000:  4500 00b7 12b7 4000 4006 2988 7f00 0001  E.....@.@.).....
0x0010:  7f00 0001 bf14 18eb ce9c 0f04 e920 abec  ................
0x0020:  8018 0401 feab 0000 xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  ................
0x0030:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  ....*3./.HTTP/1.
0x0040:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  1..Host:.localho
0x0050:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  st:6379..X-Forwa
0x0060:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  rded-For:.xx.xxx
0x0070:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  .xxx.xxx..X-Forw
0x0080:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  arded-Server:.xx
0x0090:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  .xxx.xxx.xx..Con
0x00a0:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx  nection:.Keep-Al
0x00b0:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xx                        ive....
```

As can be seen in the ASCII translation, Apache is truncating the message at the first CRLF after *3 and appending HTTP header information for forwarding, as it is suppose to. Of course Redis is replying with an error as the message is no longer formatted using the Redis Serialization Protocol (RESP).

1) Is there a way to configure Apache to blindly forward the raw TCP packets?

2) If not, is there a standard open source solution to this problem?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are you trying to do that simple NAT port forwarding won't accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelHampton encryption.

Comment: A SSH tunnel would be my choice here and not any kind of proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my intuition tells me that Apache+PHP is not an optimal solution, it was a fast and so far satisfactory one. Apache sends the HTTP message to the PHP script where the post is extracted and forwarded to redis using the loopback interface. For 'posterity' I have pasted a skeleton version of the script here.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("/some/logging.txt","a");
    $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $redisSocket = fsockopen("localhost", 6379, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$redisSocket) {
        fwrite($file, "Error: $errstr ($errno)\n");
    } else {
        fwrite($redisSocket, "$entityBody");
        $redisResponse = fgets($redisSocket);
        if (!$redisResponse) {
            fwrite($file, "No response from Redis");
        } else {
            fwrite($file, "Redis Response: $redisResponse");
        }
    }
?>
```

I try to avoid 'gluing' things together with scripts wherever possible, but so far it has provided the additional benefits of allowing me to check the input data for integrity and create custom logs and responses.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working except for appendings from Apache to the headers, then you could turn those off via mod_headers: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Thank you! mod_headers looked promising. However, to ensure the Redis command is unaltered all of the headers would need to be completely removed. After some research it seems that the **Server** header [can not be removed](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026).

Comment: I'm reaching a bit, but perhaps POST to PHP and then strip anything that you don't need.

Comment: Yes, we were throwing that idea around here as well. It is unfortunate to need glue like that, but I suppose it's warranted given that Apache probably isn't the tool for this job anyway. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Best of luck and report back with whatever solution you end up going with. Its always useful to know these things for posterity! :)